# export excel and format specific row to text

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net

I have a method for export Gridview to excel

```
        Public Sub Export2Excel(ByVal Response As HttpResponse, ByVal Control As GridView, ByVal Fname As String)
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
               Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Fname & ".xls")
        Response.Charset = "Unicode"
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

        Control.AllowPaging = False
        Control.DataBind()

        For i As Integer = 0 To Control.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim row As GridViewRow = Control.Rows(i)
            row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
            row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode")

                        Next

        Control.RenderControl(hw)

        'style to format numbers to string

        Dim style As String = "<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"
        Response.Write(style)
        Response.Output.Write(st.ToString())
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

code above export excel correctly, but it's override all `NUMBER` data type column to `text` data type, I don't need all `NUMBER` to `Text` I just need specific column to be text

**example**

```
    Account Amount
8602241158  1000.00
8602241158  1000.00
7896476479  500.00
7896476479  500.00
0986046857  900.00
```

here is sample data from Excel that all are `NUMBER` but has been override to `TEXT` by above code, then I can't summarize `Amount` column, My point is I only need to format `Account` column to `TEXT` not `Amount` column

Comment: In your for loop, you need a condition to check for Account column and do the formatting accordingly

Comment: Your code isn't creating an Excel file. It's creating an HTML file with a fake extension. Excel will try to *import* this *HTML* file using defaults but can fail for any number of reasons, like unexpected formatting tags. It's just an import operation after all.

Comment: Use a library like EPPlus to create a real Excel file. It's easier, faster, and you avoid conversion errors

Comment: thank you for your suggest.